# Customized unique Progress bar

Tags: android

I want to use a customized progress bar which u might have seen when Windows OS is booting up in the pc,like small sequential buttons horizontally or u might have seen in sony ericsson xperia phones in the top of the page when you navigate page in the Home screen but which is not a progress bar.Help me in this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you have an example here:

http://code.google.com/p/myandroidwidgets/source/browse/trunk/Custom_Progress_Bar/src/com/beanie/example/views/MyProgressBar.java

but i suggest you to look for it in google, and if you have any questions while doing it, ask the particular question.